# How to map Java Map to/from GraphQL

Tags: java, json, dictionary, graphql, schema

Looking for an elegant, existing solution to map a Java Map to/from GraphQL/JSON.

`Map<String, String> map = Map.of("a", "b", "c", "d");`

Ideally, and I believe in line with the JSON ObjectMapper, the resulting JSON should look like this:

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

The only way with vanilla GraphQL schema is to define a type with a key and a value and pack them into a list. This in turn creates bloated JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": "b"
  },
  {
    "key": "c",
    "value": "d"
  }
]
```

I've seen scalar type related answers and if it's the only way so be it.
Thanks for any pointers/tips!

Edit: I do still shy away of implementing my data object as a Map. Has anyone had any success doing so? On https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/schema-definition/ the last item of the section Field Mapping Priority intrigues me (not enough yet though):

> Last of all, if the data class implements `java.util.Map` then:
>
> method get(name)

Edit 2: after some more reading I understand now that there's no straight forward mapping between java maps and GraphQL. I will follow the scalar approach for maps as this will be good enough for most of my intended uses, ie. simply return, if desired, some settings/properties/etc. of a specific operation or query